# vb.net Function does not return value on all code paths

Tags: vb.net, browser

I made a simple function in VB.Net get gets the string you typed into textbox one, and sends it through the webbrower to text box id "wgo" and click submit afterwards.. Its giving me the warning "Function GetMessage() does not return a value on all code paths". If anyone knows how to fix the warning, or how to capture the textbox1.text message in a different format; please let me know.

Heres part of the code I'm using:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim elements = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")   '' or whatever tag it is
    For Each element As HtmlElement In elements
        GetMessage() 'Get message from textbox1 and send it 
        If element.GetAttribute("className") = "submitbut" Then
            element.InvokeMember("click")
            MsgBox("Your ECHO has been broadcast!")
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text 'Displays what the sent message was
    TextBox1.Text = ""            'Erases old message from textbox1
    TextBox3.Text = getCurrentDateTimeString()  'Displays the time and date it was sent
End Sub

Function GetMessage()
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("wgo").SetAttribute("value", TextBox1.Text)
End Function
```

Any help would be appreciated! I'm new to VB.net so take it easy on me! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Your function does not return anything at all!

It that's desired behavior you should change it to `Sub`:

```
Sub GetMessage()
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("wgo").SetAttribute("value", TextBox1.Text)
End Sub
```

Comment: HAHA, Wow. I'm so used to other languages where you can define functions and call them later. I'm not used to all the newer "function types?" VB offers. Thanks, it worked <3.

Comment: Correction: Now I'm getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." on the "WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("wgo").SetAttribute("value", TextBox1.Text)".. Any ideas? Maybe it's not recognizing "wgo" as an id?

Comment: You might want to mark this answer as correct and start a new question.